# Why is loss changing with dense and embedding layers sizes?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I have a simple model as follows:

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_size):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size)
        self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

    def call(self, x):
        return self.out(self.embedding(x))
```

My loss is calculated using softmax cross entropy and weights updated with the adam optimizer.

When vocab_size = 2 (for testing purposes), loss is this:
[image]

When vocab_size = 20200 (full size of vocab), loss is this:
[image]

Why is the shape of the loss changing, when everything is the same except for dense and embedding layer sizes? And how do I get the same, nice shape for loss with the larger vocabulary size?

Comment: What is the shape of the input to the model?

Comment: I just input (1, 1) containing 'apple' encoded to a vector, then the argmax of output is supposed to be 'pickup' when converted from a vector. This was all a smaller test of a bigger program. I think it might have to do with the model not being powerful enough to take on the larger vocab size.

Comment: I don't think the loss curves are that different, I mean, they are both steadily decreasing over the number of epochs. Your dense layer has a lot more nodes for the complete vocab, so I think maybe 100 epochs is not enough.

Could you run an experiment with more epochs for the complete vocab so we can see what the loss looks like?

For example, look at the values in the Y axis, they are still very large, maybe use some learning rate decay after N epochs. Good luck